# No sound - often problem

Tags: sound

Many times , when i open my pc the sound is dead , though when i go to system settings / audio , everything seems right. when I restart my computer the sound is back to normal again . I saw some comments with commands , but I don't know where to write these commands . Please help me with both of the problems : 
1. Where do I write the commands ? (i probably need a full explanation)
2. Is there any command to troubleshoot this ?

Answer (score 0):

To start, your question regarding where to place commands:

There is an application packaged with every ubuntu variant that has "terminal" somewhere in the title.

- gnome-terminal
- kterminal
- lxterm

This is your interface to the `command line` or a text only terminal on the system. I will assume you're coming from a Windows background, and the easiest (But not necessarily proper) comparison would be to the windows command prompt.

*note* The author does not condone copy/pasting commands into a terminal that you do not understand. This can have irreversible side effects on your system and should be performed with supervision of an experienced user. If one is not available, I recommend you join #ubuntu on irc.freenode.net and ask for a mentor.

Now on to troubleshooting your sound issues:

Reference the following community documentation: [Community Documentation: Sound Troubleshooting Procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)

The easiest method to troubleshoot is to force pulse audio to restart

**1A. If you are using Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS** (Precise Pangolin) or later, try this first:

```
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*
```

wait ten seconds, then run this:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

**1B. Should the approach above fail to correct the problem** (it is only known to work on some variations), you can try this next. If you are using Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (Precise Pangolin) or later:

```
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*
```

wait 10 seconds, then reboot (putting the machine to sleep is not enough -- fully power it off and then back on). Make sure to save your work first.