# Troubleshoot intermittent 'no sound' problem

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Sometimes, when I start my Ubuntu Xenial desktop, it dosn't output any sound. A restart or two always does the trick, but I'd like to understand what goes wrong.

I do have the usual output devices listed in sound settings, but nothing I do there (including switching back and forth between devices) fixes the issue. Neither does running `killall pulseaudio`, removing `~/.config/pulse` and `~/.pulse*`, then restarting pulseaudio, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/408391/142526).

What logs should I look at, or what application output can help pinpointing the cause of this issue?

P.S.
My audio device information:

```
$ sudo lspci -v
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a2f0
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8735
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 150
    Memory at df340000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at df320000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Answer (score 0):

difficult to tell without full vendor/device ID ...

eg. the `8086:a2f0` would be a `200 Series PCH HD Audio` device.

please add output of `sudo lspci -nnk` and maybe compare once a) when it does not work with b) when it works, by entering `dmesg -t | egrep "(audio|snd|hda)"` after booting up.

most likely you'll have to `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and specify the sound card model & options there (see [driver database](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1043568)), `options snd-hda-intel model=...` in order to work around failed detection attempts - or slightly different hardware configurations, caused by an actual hardware/firmware issue.

the HDMI drivers of some graphics adapters might occasionally interfere with other HDMI drivers from a sound-card/chip... where removing the conflicting kernel module and using just a single one HDMI output, helps.

there even is an [Sound Troubleshooting Procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) manual ...